# Copy Range of cells to Visio (2013) using VBA code

Tags: vba, excel, visio

I have an Excel range of cells (let's call it "Table A") and I would like to copy that Range/Table into Visio using VBA.

Without VBA - I can copy the range in Excel, go to Visio - Insert - Chart - go to Sheet1 tab - Paste

Using VBA - I am a novice so this is what I think it should look something like:

```
Set AppVisio = CreateObject("visio.Application")
AppVisio.Visible = True

AppVisio.Documents.AddEx "basicd_u.vst", 0, 0
        Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("TABLEA").Copy _
        AppVisio.ActiveWindow.Page.Add.Paste
```

Comment: Does your code work? If not, at what point does it seem to break? Please be specific when asking for help with existing code!

Comment: Looks like you're 99% there. Make the copy and paste operations two distinct instructions (i.e. remove that line continuation), and that could possibly work. If not, [edit] your question to describe how it's failing, what error you're getting.